# How do you add certain values in map based off of user input?

Tags: c++, maps

I'm trying to make a [Gematria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gematria) calculator in c++ and want to get the same results i am getting in java. How would I get so in C++ it could print the sum of the values from what the user inputs and get the same ultimate result as I would in Java? Please note I'm a beginner at C++ so please forgive me for any ignorance in this question.

I managed [thanks to stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62987856/how-do-you-add-up-certain-values-in-hashtable-based-off-of-user-input) to make one in Java. In Java I have I could enter multiple words and get the Gematria, and I want to get the same results in C++.

**Java Code**

```
package com.company;
`import java.util.Hashtable;`
`import java.util.Scanner;`

public class English_Gematria {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     Hashtable<String, Integer> Gematria_Values = new Hashtable<>();
     Gematria_Values.put(" ", 0);
     Gematria_Values.put("A", 1);
     Gematria_Values.put("B", 2);
     Gematria_Values.put("C", 3);
// Goes through rest of alphabet.
System.out.println("What do you want the gematria of?");
Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);
String Gematria = i.nextline();
int sum = 0;
for (int j = 0; Gematria.length(); j++) {
    sum += Gematria_Values.get(String.valueOf(Gematria.toUpperCase().charAt(j)));
}
System.out.println("The Gematria of " + Gematria + " is " + sum);
```

**C++ Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
std::map<std::string, std::double_t> Gematria_Values;
Gematria_Values[" "] = 0;
Gematria_Values["A"] = 1;
Gematria_Values["B"] = 2;
Gematria_Values["C"] = 3;
//  Goes through rest of alphabet.
std::string Gematria;
std::cout << "What do you want the gematria of?" << std::endl;
std::cin >> Gematria;
transform(Gematria.begin(), Gematria.end(), Gematria.begin(), ::toupper);
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Gematria.length(); i++)
{ 
sum += Gematria_Values.at(Gematria);
}
std::cout << "The Gematria is " << sum;

return 0;

}
```

In C++ when user input is (without the quotes) "a" or "A" I get

```
The Gematria is 1.
```

When the user input is (without the quotes) "b" or "B" I get

```
The Gematria is 2.
```

However when the user input is (without the quotes) "ab" or "bb" I get

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  map::at
```

My question is: How would I get the same the ultimate result as I do in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- if I understand your problem the key type of the map should be `char` and not string. The same should apply to the java version.
- see [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](http://Why%20is%20%E2%80%9Cusing%20namespace%20std;%E2%80%9D%20considered%20bad%20practice?)
- we don't use [`std::double_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/float_t). Honestly I've never even heard of this until now. Use `double`.
- by default [prefer `std::unordered_map` over `std::map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196995/is-there-any-advantage-of-using-map-over-unordered-map-in-case-of-trivial-keys).
- you can simplify the initialization of standard containers using initializer list (see code)

```
int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<char, double> Gematria_Values = {
        {' ', 0},
        {'A', 1},
        {'B', 2},
        {'C', 3}
    };

    std::string Gematria;
    std::cout << "What do you want the gematria of?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> Gematria;
    transform(Gematria.begin(), Gematria.end(), Gematria.begin(), ::toupper);

    int sum = 0;
    for (auto ch : Gematria)
        sum += Gematria_Values[ch];
        
    std::cout << "The Gematria is " << sum;
}
```

`Gematria_Values[ch];` [behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at): in case `ch` is not found in the map it creates and inserts a default new pair into the map (with key `ch` and value `0`).

If you want (you should) check for valid user input: You can stick with [`at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/at) which will throw or, if you don't want/need exceptions you can do:

```
for (auto ch : Gematria)
{
    auto found = Gematria_Values.find(ch);
    if (found == Gematria_Values.end())
    {
        // deal with error
    }
    else
    {
        sum += found->second;
    }
}
```